# Get Element using BeautifulSoup that does not have a class in HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

I am trying to get the text of the user's rank from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/leecming) webpage. By "rank" I mean the text you see in the top right corner of the user's info:

[image: here]

In this example rank is "Competitions Master". So how do I get that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see clearly after inspecting the rank there's `<a href = "/progression"` inside of which is a `<p>` tag and inside of which there's again a `<p>`tag which contains the rank.

First find the container with `<a href = "/progression"` and then find all the `<p>` tags inside it then again find all `<p>`. Print the text present inside the `<p>`tag as there is only one `<p>` tag inside`<a href = "/progression"` then `<p>`.

Or there's a second method too: There's a button below "Home" with the name of the rank. You can try scraping that element.